# Is “Songify” a well-received word as an English neology?

Tags: verbs, american-english, suffixes, is-it-a-word

I came across the word “*songify*” for the first time in the article of October 23 NY Times titled ‘Yes We Chant’ with the sub-head, “The Gregory Brothers songify the debate, with Gregorian chanting.”

The article is accompanied with a video, in which CBC’s Bob Schieffer as the moderator of this Monday’s Presidential debate, President Obama and Gov. Mitt Romney all “songify” clips of their statements.

The text reads:

> “Our only remaining option was to *songify* the whole thing ourselves,
>   to imagine the parallel universe where Gregorian chanting monks
>   shepherded the candidates through the debate as Bob Schieffer dropped
>   verse after verse. We hope that whoever wins this blasted election
>   will be kind enough to sing his acceptance speech.”

Although www.definition of net. defines “Songify” as “1. to make stuff into a song. 2. to make a song out of stuff that wasn't originally intended to be a song, none of credible English dictionaries including Oxford, Cambridge, and Merriam-Webster registers “songify.”

As there is no instance of this word in GoogleNgram viewer either, we cannot tell since when and how the word “*Songify*” came into currency.

Is “*Songify*” a well-received word in modern or American English? Or is it just a wild and ephemeral journalism neology? Is it possible to say, or coin “Musicify,” "Medlefy,” “Lyricify” and “Poemify” likewise?

Comment: The word *poemify* has the problem that it's a synonym of the already-existing word *versify*.

Comment: Related: *[What is the difference between the suffixes -ize and -ify?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189530)* Apparently, the suffix "-ify" is mainly used directly after a stressed syllable, so "musicify", "lyricify" and "poemify" are a bit awkwardly formed, and people might prefer the sound of "musicize", "lyricize", and "poemize".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd like to address the last part of your question:

> Is “Songify” a well-received word in modern or American English?  Is it possible to say, or coin “Musicify,” “Medlefy,” “Lyricify” and “Poemify” likewise?

The *-ify* suffix is well-established, and is used in [relatively common words](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=personify,%20deify,%20exemplify,%20preachify,%20compactify,%20historify,%20webify&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) such as *personify, deify*, and *exemplify*. [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/ify) defines it like this:

> used with some adjectives and nouns to make verbs meaning “to become, or to make someone or something become, something”

Browsing through [OneLook's reverse dictionary results](http://www.onelook.com/?w=%2aify) for more examples, I found a heap of other [lesser-heard](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=preachify,compactify,historify,webify&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) words as well, such as *[preachify](http://www.onelook.com/?w=preachify), [compactify](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/compactify), [historify](http://www.wordnik.com/words/historify)*, and even the technojargon *[webify](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=webify)*. (Some of those are so rare that my spell-checker doesn't even like them.)

So, can you coin your own word, such as *musicify* or *poetify*?  Evidently so, because the *Times* writer did just that, even though *songify* doesn't appear to have crept into any [dictionaries](http://www.onelook.com/?w=songify&ls=a) yet. That said, I would recommend using non-established *-ify* words cautiously and sparingly; used too flippantly, they can inadvertently *amateurify* an entire paragraph or passage.  More often than not, I'd probably go with “*made* (or *converted*, or *wrote*) *into lyrics*” before springing *lyrify* on my readers or listeners.

Answer (score 4):

This may also be an example of branding seeping into the language, ala kleenex.  [Songify](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/songify/id438735719?mt=8) is an app that turns speech into a song, and has been a [YouTube meme](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MX0D4oZwCsA&feature=BFa&list=ELVok5zsqhwo8) for a while now.  It's ability to work into the language seems a simple extension of that app's purpose.

The meaning would be clear, in that "-ify" applied as a suffix to song is obviously denoting "to make into a song," but it is not anything with an established pedigree.