# What is the difference between the suffixes -ize and -ify?

Tags: verbs, suffixes, morphology

The dictionary ascribes the same purpose to both these suffixes: to denote 'to make, or become'.

However, for some neologisms, *-ize* seems much more appropriate than *-ify* does, and vice-versa. 
There must be some reason for this.

Is there a rule that governs, or describes, when to use one over the other?

Comment: Dictionaries can only hint at the uses of suffixes; you need a grammar. Both of these are causative/inchoative suffixes, two of many in English; that's why they gave them the lame meaning 'to make, or become'. _Make_ is used for some causative constructions: _Make it so; He made me do it_, and _become_ means and originates as _come to be_, which is standard inchoative paraphrase. But the dictionary didn't tell you, because that's not what dictionaries do.

Comment: Note there are a two other, though rarer, suffixes which "*ify*" the verb: *-ate* and *-en*, as in "*flourinate*" and "*blacken*" respectively. A quick Google Books search turned up "Word Formation in English" (Cambridge Press) which goes into this in some detail on pp 92-94, and even makes an observation about neologisms tending toward *-ize*, as OP does. Unfortunately, the explanation is mostly gobbledygook to me, but if someone can translate this into non-technical language, that would make a really solid answer (and earn a +1 from me). http://books.google.com/books?id=78KFCIHtJS4C&pg=PA93

Comment: @JohnLawler Why don't they? That seems like information people might want from a dictionary.

Comment: @Hal: Dictionaries exist to document meanings and pronunciation of words ("lexical items"). They're lists; long lists, with sublists, but just lists. They don't -- and can't, not with lists -- describe all the ways the words can go together. That is a different kind of book, called a _Grammar of English_, not a _Dictionary of English_. This is because there is an enormous amount more to grammar than just stringing words together like beads on a string. Dictionaries can only list the beads, not describe all the possible correct and (and not the incorrect) necklaces one could make.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Courtesy of @DanBron, here's what it says in [Word Formation in English](http://books.google.com/books?id=78KFCIHtJS4C&pg=PA93),
with interpolated translations:

> **-ify**
>   This suffix attaches to three kinds of base word:
>    1. monosyllabic words
>    2. words stressed on the final syllable
>    3. words stressed on the next-to-last syllable that end in unstressed /i/
>
> Neologisms usually do not show stress shift, but some older forms do
>   (*húmid ~ humídify, sólid, solídify*).

Translation: there are restrictions on what kind of words *-ify* can go on. They have to **sound** right. Examples of each kind of word root with *-ify*:

1. *pacify, crucify, gentrify* (two Latin words and a neologism, all from monosyllabic roots)
2. *solemnify, malignify, machinify* (likewise 2 Latin, one neo; but these are rarer)
3. *shabbify, rubify, calcify* (ditto)

> These restrictions have the effect that *-ify* is in (almost) complementary distribution with the suffix *-ize*.

Translation: the set of roots that can take *-ify* and the set of roots that can take *-ize* are (almost) disjoint sets. There is one intersection, which will be described next.

> The only, but systematic, exception to the complementarity of *-ize/-ify* can be observed with (2), the base words in /i/, which take *-ify* with loss of the final /i/ (as in *Nazify* /'natsəfai/), or take *-ize* with no accompanying segmental changes apart from optional glide insertion (as in *Nazi-ize* /'natsi(y)aiz/).

Translation: you can do it either way with words stressed on the next-to-last syllable that end in unstressed /i/. But they're the only ones.

> Semantically, *-ify* shows the same range of meanings as *-ize* and the two suffixes could therefore be considered phonologically conditioned allomorphs.

Translation: *-ify* and *-ize* can be considered "the same morpheme", just like *a* and *an*.

> **-ize**
>   Both -ize and -ify are polysemous suffixes, which express a whole range of related concepts such as locative, provisional, causative/factitive, resultative, inchoative, performative, similative.

Translation: there are a lot of kinds of meaning (*poly-semous* < Gk 'many meanings') for the suffix. These types have technical names. Examples follow (I've changed a few old-fashioned terms to protect the innocent).

> **Locatives** are paraphrased as 'put into `X`, as in *computerize, hospitalize, tubify*.
>    - *Patinaize, fluoridize, youthify* are **provisional** ('provide with `X`'),
>    - *randomize, functionalize, humidify* are **causative** ('make (more) `X`'),
>    - *carbonize, itemize, trustify,* and *nazify* are **resultative** ('make into `X`'),
>    - *aerosolize* and *mucify* are **inchoative** ('become `X`'),
>    - *anthropologize* and *speechify* are **performative** ('perform `X`')
>    - *cannibalize* and *vampirize* can be analyzed as **similitive** ('act like `X`').
>
> The suffix *-ize* attaches primarily to roots ending in an unstressed syllable and the resulting derivatives show rather complex patterns of base allormorphy.

Translation: A lot of funny things happen to the roots when adding *-ize*. Examples follow.

> For example, bases are systematically truncated (i.e, they lose the rime of the final syllable) if they are vowel-final and end in two unstressed syllables (truncated *memory ~ memorize* vs untruncated consonant-final *hospital ~ hospitalize*). Furthermore, polysyllabic derivatives in -ize are not allowed to have identical onsets in the last two syllables, if these are unstressed. In the pertinent cases truncation is used as a repair strategy, as in *feminine ~ feminize* and *emphasis ~ emphasize*.

Translation: most of the non-neologisms were formed in Latin, under Latin phonological and morphological rules, which don't apply to English. So lots of the roots are not really English words, but rather are **related** to English words, and it gets very complicated trying to account for all the differences between the roots and the words.

This is one example of how complex even a teensy-weensy part of English grammar can get.
And this isn't even syntax.

Answer (score -1):

The suffix -fy is French fier (to make), from Latin ficare, belonging to the word familiy facere/ficere, to make. Example pacify from pax/pacis peace, pacificare to make peace. See Etymonline  http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=-fy&searchmode=none

Comment: I downvoted because this doesn't answer the original question.