# What kind of morphemes do you call -ish and -y? How would you describe their function?

Tags: neologisms, morphology

In the context of neologisms and/or teenspeak: e.g. soon-ish, tumblr-y

Comment: '-ish' and '-y' are new and strange sounding because they take one part of speech to another different from usual. '-ish' usually goes from adejective to adjective but this is from adverb to adjective, and and '-y' from adjective to adverb but this is from noun or verb to adjective.

Comment: They are sometimes used to add comedic value to a sentence.

Comment: Related: [*What is the difference between the suffixes -ize and -ify*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189530/what-is-the-difference-between-the-suffixes-ize-and-ify); see in particular the reference to "*Word Formation in English*" (Cambridge Press), which is a good resource and reference for this kind of question. [Page 94](http://books.google.com/books?id=78KFCIHtJS4C&pg=PA93#v=onepage&q=ify&f=false) partially answers this question.

Answer (score 1):

They may be considered approximator-characterizer suffixes and the morpheme from a-c-ization an "acization" (placeholder, temporarylogism).  Though neither *-ish* nor, especially, *-y* is new (/place/-ish = of /place/'s character or origin: *British* ), newer uses (from *hungry-ish* right down to *sortof-ish*) appear weirder.

Comment: Waiting for word *y.* *Ish* is already a word.