# Is 'botifed' the right word to say humans are behaving more like robots?

Tags: neologisms

From this article:
*"We generally view the machine/human divide as a one-way street of advancing technology. Machines, we are repeatedly told, are becoming more human-like—but humans are also becoming more botifed."*

https://qz.com/944470/bots-are-sounding-more-like-humans-but-humans-are-sounding-more-like-bots/

Even though it is not a word, I would have expected 'botified', but 'botifed' feels totally unusual.

Comment: It looks like a typo to me, probably not caught because *botified* isn't a standard word, either (and so not in any spell checker).

Comment: my issue with it has more to do with the "ify" part (or ified). .. I'd prefer bot-like perhaps?  I supposed the ified  relates more to other techs used to transform non humans though

Comment: He uses the word "botifed" twice in the article, so not sure if that's a typo.

Comment: Google Books claims only 62 instances of [*robotified*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22robotified%22), against 308 of my preferred [*roboticised*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22roboticised%22). (Both swamped by 2280 instances of AmE [*roboticized*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22roboticized%22), obviously! :)

Comment: In some contexts, "[Cyborged](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780195305678.001.0001/acref-9780195305678-e-105)" may be an alternative.

Comment: Maybe he means people are being fed by robots.

Comment: Actually, is bot a robot, or is it a mini program with a single function? Humans may become more mechanical or robotic without becoming more botic.

Comment: (Certainly "botified" is a term that most folks in the US (and probably the UK) would comprehend and interpret in roughly the appropriate way. And it's much catchier than any of the proposed alternatives.)

Comment: You mean *bottify* and *bottified*, right? That needs the same double-t that *botted* has.

Comment: I actually put an answer "Robotic" below, and while I think that is a fine, and perhaps more gramatical word, I DO understand a difference in flavoring evolving between something that might be "like a 'bot'" and something "robotic" .. Robot is more a physical thing that performs physical actions...sometimes repetitively sometimes responsively, while a "bot" is more of a "script" or "app" as in "chat bot" ... auto-didactically ?  (not that a 'bot' can't be responsive.. but it emphasises something less physical that 'robot' is reserved more for these days.

Comment: @sumelic Not to mention—particularly apposite here—another neologism: _Spotify_.

Comment: Perhaps it is a misprint for “bottle-fed”. (As opposed to having been weaned, and being able to cut up their meat themselves.)

Answer (score 3):

As others have said in the comments, the two instances of "botifed" that you observed are certainly a typo for "botif***i***ed." The spelling "botified" is in fact also used twice in the article.

[The suffix "-ify"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189530/what-is-the-difference-between-the-suffixes-ize-and-ify) /ɪfaɪ/ (which turns into "-ified" /ɪfaɪd/ when you add "-ed") is a somewhat productive, if informal, way of turning monosyllabic nouns into verbs with a meaning something like "to make into [the noun]". "Humans are also becoming more botified" means something like "Humans are becoming more like robots".

Some suffixes, such as *-er,* cause a single consonant letter to double after a stressed "short" vowel, but there isn't an established consonant-doubling rule for words suffixed with *-ify.* The spelling *botify* is reasonably regular; other comparable examples are the brand name *Spotify* (as Janus Bahs Jacquet mentioned in a comment), *gasify* (which seems to be a much more common spelling of this word than "gassify"), *manify* (which actually has an OED entry!), and *slugify* (which seems to be used as programming jargon).

Spontaneously created *-ify* words are sometimes written with a hyphen before the suffix and quotation marks around the word.

Answer (score 0):

I would use "robotic" rather than "botified", as it is a proper English adjective.

Comment: Hello, George. This is a 'comment' rather than an 'answer' on ELU.

Comment: "Cybernetic" might be a better word choice, but it is unclear to me if this word as used in pop-culture conforms to the strict definition(s) of "cybernetic." Certainly a cyborg is accepted as a machine-augmentation to a biological organism.

Comment: The phrasing suggests that this is speaking to traits and behavior, rather than the presence or absence of components.  The term "cybernetic" doesn't really convey much other than "machine-augmented biological", but "robotic" definitely could describe behavior.