# Why is there an extra "t" in Lemmatization?

Tags: nouns, orthography, suffixes

When we say :

> - Specify, it becomes Specification (no t)
> - Value, it becomes Valuation (no t)
> - Custom, it becomes Customization (no t)

Lemma is a code used in programming, to describe the process of doing this Lemma, the word used is "Lemmatization".

I wonder where did the "t" in *Lemmatization* come from?

https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/stemming-and-lemmatization-1.html

Comment: Among the three words, you've got *ication*, *ation*, and *tization* added—so there's more different between those than just the *t*. I also note that both *specify* and *value* lose their last letter before the rest is added, but that *lemma* does not. Maybe it would be a more direct comparison if you gave *custom → customization* as one of the examples? (Although even then, that word ends in a consonant rather than a vowel.) So far, I haven't seen a pattern of any kind for a direct comparison between the base words and what's added—so, *lemma* doesn't stand out as an exception . . .

Comment: Note that the root for specify is _specific_.

Comment: Because "lemmaize" would be difficult to pronounce clearly.  Generally speaking, when "izing" a word that ends in a vowel the "t" is added to separate the syllables (or some longer root is used which provides the needed consonant).

Comment: This was a really weird thing to be wonder about, in my opinion. Definitely +1 for that. It's nerdiness level 100 on this one and I'm filled with utmost admiration and respect. May I inquiry as to how you came up with it? What made you consider such a immensely useless thing (still being information gold nugget)? I'm so impressed...

Comment: @DonkeyBanana Lemmatization sounds like Limitization except Limitization origion "Limit" has T, Why would Limit end up similar to Lemma ?!

Comment: @JasonBassford it's not so much that you drop the *y* in *specify* before adding *ication,* but rather that the *y* changes into an *i* because they essentially represent the same sound.  Historically, the *i* changed into a *y* because people decided that they didn't like ending words with *i* or, as was used for some time, *ie.*  A casual glance at a couple of etymologies suggests that the *c* was lost somewhere between Latin and French.

Comment: @MontyHarder but no, it seems rather that "specify" is derived from "specific," not the other way around.  This happened in Latin, where the adjective *specificus* (derived in part from *facio,* meaning *make)* gave rise to the verb *specifico.*  Futhermore, *-ation* forms are not derived from adjectives but from verbs.

Comment: @phoog that makes more sense.

Comment: @asmgx So impressed. I wish I could +1 you once again.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

#### "Lemma" is from a Greek word that had t in some of its forms

Etymologically, the *t* in *lemmatize* comes from the stem of the Greek word *λῆμμα,* which is the source of the English word *lemma*. Greek nouns have many inflected forms: the citation form *λῆμμα* is just the nominative (and accusative) singular form. Most other forms of a Greek noun are built on a stem that often differs at the end from the nominative singular form. Greek has many neuter nouns ending in *-μα* (*-ma*) with stems ending in *-ματ-* (*-mat-*). Conventionally, the inflected form used to identify the stem of a Greek noun is the genitive singular, which for *λῆμμα* is *λήμματος* (*lemmatos*). By removing the *-ος,* you can identify the stem *lemmat-.* The nominative and accusative plural *λήμματα* (*lemmata*) is built on the same stem.

#### Some other English words follow the same pattern

Most English speakers don't know these kinds of details about the etymology of words like *lemma* or about how Greek nouns inflect. They just memorize the form of the English word *lemmatize*, possibly aided by analogy with other pairs of similarly related words.

A number of other Greek *-μα* nouns have entered English as *-ma* nouns and show the same variation with *-mat-* in derived words:

- stigma, stigmatize
- asthma, asthmatic
- trauma, traumatic, traumatize
- aroma, aromatic, aromatize
- enigma, enigmatic
- cinema, cinematic
- drama, dramatic, dramatize

There are also some English nouns ending in *-m* that are from Greek neuter nouns ending in *-μα* and that are related to words containing *-mat-*:

- system, systematic, systematize
- problem, problematic, problematize
- emblem, emblematic
- symptom, symptomatic
- sperm, spermatic

But *custom* is not such a noun. I don't think there's any easy way to figure that out aside from looking up its etymology.

#### /t/ is not just automatically inserted after any vowel followed by *-ize,* although there might be some non-automatic tendency towards /t/-insertion in certain contexts

As I mentioned, most speakers are not aware of the etymological source of the *t* in *lemmatize.*

Some comments and answers have brought up an idea that from a synchronic (as opposed to diachronic) perspective, the /t/ in *lemmatize* could be analyzed as a consonant that is inserted to prevent hiatus (a sequence of two vowels in separate syllables with no intervening consonant).

I don't think that's an untenable hypothesis, but I wanted to say that any such process of /t/-insertion before *-ize* is not incredibly productive, and is more limited than just a rule like "*-tize* is used after vowels".

Looking at other words ending in /ə/ spelled *-a*, we see the following alternatives to inserting /t/ before *-ize*:

- hiatus with a possible change in vowel quality (that could be viewed as introducing a front glide): 
  algebra > algebraize /-eɪaɪz/ or /-əaɪz/
- dropping the first vowel: 
   [formulize](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/formulize), [silicize](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/silicize), [nebulize](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nebulize), [patinize](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/patinize)

If we look at other vowels, we also see those alternative strategies being used fairly frequently. Dropping the first vowel is very common with bases ending in /i/:

- jeopardize, scrutinize, summarize, agonize, theorize, notarize,
  anatomize, empathize, eulogize, prioritize, botanize, alchemize,
  etymologize, militarize, melodize, theologize, lobotomize,
  strategize, astronomize, philosophize, memorize,
  allegorize, sorcerize, prioritize

For bases ending in /oʊ/, hiatus (which could be viewed as involving a back glide) seems no less common than t-insertion. Hiatus occurs in *[ghettoize](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ghettoize), [heroize](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/heroize), [jumboize](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/jumboize),* and *[memoize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).* The only case of t-insertion after /oʊ/ that I know of is *egotize,* which coexists with a less frequent alternative form with hiatus, *[egoize](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=egotize%2C%20egoize&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cegotize%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cegoize%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cegotize%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cegoize%3B%2Cc0).*

For non-rhotic speakers, there are a great many words ending in the sound /ə/ with spellings that end in the letter R. When such words are suffixed with *-ize,* the consonant sound /r/ is inserted after the /ə/, as in the following list:

- characterize, rubberize, rasterize, vulgarize, vascularize, exteriorize, valorize, factorize

Comment: In addition to the Greek derivation (which I really didn't know about until now), there's the fact that it's just easier to pronounce.  Try wrapping your tongue around "lemmaize". "stigmaic", &c.

Comment: The glottal stop that would be outright required in *lemma'ize* isn't probably not by coincidence an allophone of *t* in various accents that have t-glottalization.

Comment: @jamesqf: There are some words that end in *-aize* or *-aic,* like *Judaize* and *Judaic, archaize* and *archaic, algebraize* and *algebraic.* The *-a-* in these words is not pronounced the same as a word-final *-a*. Another possibility for words with final *-a* is for the derived word to remove the *-a*, as in *silica, silicic* or *chimera, chimeric.*

Comment: Lovely to see some Greek on a Monday morning. I wanted to see "schema, schematic" in your list though, as it's a favourite word of mine.

Comment: In a few of these cases, the Greek plural, with its t, is also present in English: lemmata,stigmata, schemata.

Comment: This is very cool and all, but mostly just makes me sad that "enigmatize" isn't a word.

Comment: @GregSchmidt [Who says it's not](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enigmatize)?

Answer (score 24):

[Etymonline states](https://www.etymonline.com/word/lemma#etymonline_v_30747):

> 1560s, in mathematics, from Greek lemma (**plural lemmata**) "something received or taken; an argument; something taken for granted,"
>   (emphasis mine)

This is where the 'T' comes from. In addition, note that *lemma* derives from Greek, whereas your other examples come from Latin through French. This would account for the difference in forms.

Answer (score 0):

You’re confusing the issue by including “-ation”. 
Your question boils down to this:

> - “Specify” is a verb; it becomes “specification”⁠ (no added “t”).
> - Value is often a noun, but it can be used as a verb
>     (see [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=value), [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/value),
>     and [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/value)). 
>     But “valuate” means (approximately) the same as the verb form of “value”,
>     so it’s no surprise that we get “valuation”⁠ (no added “t”).        
>     [Related Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=value_NOUN%2Cvalue_VERB%2Cvaluate&year_start=1800)
> - “Custom” is a noun and an adjective. 
>     The verb form is “customize”, so it becomes “customization”⁠ (no added “t”).
> - The verb for the process of doing making a “lemma” is “lemmatize”.

What’s happening is:

- We add the suffix “-ize” to a noun
  to get a verb meaning “to make or become”, as discussed in
  [What is the difference between the suffixes -ize and -ify?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/189530/26083)
- But “lemmaize” would be hard to read and pronounce. 
  Spelling it “lemmaïze” or “lemma–ize” wouldn’t help much. 
  When we add “-ize” to a noun that ends with a vowel,
  we inject a “t” to make it readable and pronounceable. 
  Other examples include “dramatize”, “anesthetize”, “monetize”,
  “stigmatize” and “traumatize”.

So,

> - ”lemma” + “ize” → “lemmatize”
> - “lemmatize” → “lemmatization”