# Villainize / demonize a thing / abstract object

Tags: single-word-requests

Villainize is a great word to use if one wants to flag some kind of negative bias. However, it seems to carry an implied usage for people: things that can't be anthropomorphized may not sound quite right. To illustrate:

> I've never came across anyone who _______ certificates of deposits and
> money market funds as much/scornfully as him.

If we inserted "villainizes" there, the meaning is clear enough, but there is a part of me that wants to do better, if possible, while keeping the sentence structure intact. Has anyone any comments / suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Vilify***

> to say or write unpleasant things about someone or ***something***, in order to *cause other people to have a bad opinion of them*
>
> - In fact, they ***vilified*** the international market to such an extent that foreign military threats and hostile foreign diplomacy became insignificant.
>   ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vilify))

You could also use ***[denigrate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/denigrate)*** or ***[discredit](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/discredit)***, but they are weaker than *vilify*.

Comment: Good choice. I might add *malign* to the list.

Comment: Note that the English causative suffixes [_-ize_ and _-ify_ are in complementary distribution](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/189565/15299). _Villain_ takes _-ize_, but the bare stem _vili-_  takes _-ify_. It's the same word, though used for different purposes. Which is the way it worked out. Just evolution.

Comment: The word "disparage" would also work well there.